# Maya Python append a button into a list creates 2 UI elements

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to create an automated way of adding elements to my UI interface and deleting them when needed.
The functionality is there, on button press I create an instance of the translateUI class and with the other button I can remove it.
The issue lies within the def setBoolOn(self, *args).

**btnList.append(self.delBtnFetch)** is creating a second button in the UI and I cannot figure out why. [Clicking the 'Add' button once generates 2 buttons, even though the function only creates one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvkTw.png).
When commenting out the btnList.append, it only creates a single button, but the rest of the code breaks, when trying to remove it.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

class UI(object):
    #Constructor    
    def __init__(self):
    
    #global counter, classList, sequence
    self.btnList = []
    global counter
    counter = 1
    classList.clear()
    btnList.clear()
    
    #define name, size and title
    self.window = 'Animation_Window'
    self.title = 'Animation Automator'
    self.size = (400,560)
                
    #close window if open
    if cmds.window(self.window, exists=True) :
        cmds.deleteUI(self.window, window=True)
                
    #create new window
    self.window = cmds.window(self.window, title=self.title, widthHeight=self.size, sizeable=False)
                
    #specify layout for window
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
        
    #test text
    cmds.text('Text in class')
    
    #add button
    self.btnChckBoxOn = cmds.button(label='Add', c=self.setBoolOn) 
    #remove button
    self.btnChckBoxOff = cmds.button(label='Remove', c=self.setBoolOff)            
                                    
    #display window
    cmds.showWindow()
 
############################
##Add button functionality##    

def setBoolOn(self, *args):
    #button check
    btnChckOn = cmds.button(self.btnChckBoxOn, query=True)
    global counter
    self.classList = []
    #add 1 to the counter
    if counter >= 0:
        counter = counter + 1
        #create, based on sequence, the translateUI class
        self.sequence = translateUI(counter)

        #add the sequence class to a list
        classList.append(self.sequence)

        #get the button from translate
        self.delBtnFetch = translateUI(0).delBtn

        #add the delBtn to a list
        btnList.append(self.delBtnFetch)
        print(btnList) 

###############################
##remove button functionality##
                            
def setBoolOff(self, *args):
    #button check
    btnChckOff = cmds.button(self.btnChckBoxOff, query=True)
    global counter, classList
    #substract one off the counter
    if counter >= 1:
        counter = counter - 1

        #get the last class in the list
        lastSequence = classList[-1]

        #set the last class instance to null
        lastSequence = Null()

        #get the last button in the list
        lastButton = btnList[-1]

        #remove the last button from list
        btnList.remove(lastButton)

        #delete last button from the UI
        cmds.deleteUI(lastButton)
    else :
        print('You cannot remove all Sequences') 
              
#initiate window class        
myWindow = UI()

#######################
##Additional UI class##
#######################

class translateUI():
    def __init__(self, counter):
        global delBtn
        self.delBtn = cmds.button(l='Animate', c=self.AnimatePress)
        
        
    def AnimatePress(self, *args):
        btnAnimate = cmds.button(self.delBtn, query=True)
        print('Animation Pressed')    


##############
##VOID class##
    
class Null():
    pass
```

I am not that insanely experienced with Python yet and am at a loss here, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. First, your indentation is not correct. Then you use some global variables but I do not see any need for global variables, e.g. in your translateUI class, you define `global delBtn` and then you initialize the instance variable self.delBtn what is something completly different. It seems that you think you need to declare variables as global before using them as self.xxx but this is not the case. And if I try to execute the code it failes because there is a mismatch of global and instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know its super messy I started learning not long ago :)  I will take a look at what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `setBoolOn()` method, the `translateUI` class is initialized twice as you can see here

```py
# >> first translate UI instance was created
self.sequence = translateUI(counter)

self.classList.append(self.sequence)

# >> second translate UI instance was created
self.delBtnFetch = translateUI(0).delBtn
```

now each time it gets initiated, it will create a button for you, as that's how you declared it.

```py
class translateUI():
    def __init__(self, counter):
        global delBtn
        # >> you're creating a button during the initialization
        self.delBtn = cmds.button(l='Animate', c=self.AnimatePress)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use your code but I guess what you're trying to do is something like this:

```py
from maya import cmds
import sys


# I'm trying to create an automated way of adding elements to my UI interface and deleting them when needed.

def userInput():
    user_input = cmds.promptDialog(title="Control Info", message="name,label", style="text",
                                   button=['OK', 'Cancel'], defaultButton='OK',
                                   cancelButton='Cancel', dismissString='Aborted'
                                   )
    if user_input == 'OK':
        ranges = cmds.promptDialog(query=True, text=True)
    else:
        print('closed')
        # force to stop the script
        sys.exit()
    return ranges.split(",")


def setParentLayout(*args):
    """ Set the parent one level up in the current active window"""
    cmds.setParent('..')
    print ("MOVED the parent to: {0}".format(cmds.setParent(q=True)))

def addButtons(*args):
    """ Add a button to the current parent """
    # get control type and name
    description = userInput()

    # a dynamic dictionnary to extend for more buttons
    ctrl_dict = {"button": cmds.button, "checkBox": cmds.checkBox}

    # create the control
    ctrl_cmd = ctrl_dict[description[0]]
    the_ctrl = ctrl_cmd()

    # If it's not a layout, use the label
    if not cmds.layout(the_ctrl, q=True, ex=True):
        ctrl_cmd(the_ctrl, e=True, l=description[1])

    print("ADDED A BUTTON: {0}".format(the_ctrl))
    # update the list
    controls.append(the_ctrl)


def addLayout(*args):
    """ Add a layout to the current parent """
    lay = cmds.columnLayout()
    controls.append(lay)
    print("ADDED A LAYOUT: {0}".format(controls))


def removeButtons(*args):
    """ remove one by one anything that the user created"""
    for button_name in controls.__reversed__():
        if cmds.control(button_name, q=True, ex=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(button_name)
            print("DELETED CONTROL: {0}".format(button_name))

            # update my list
            controls.remove(button_name)
        break

# A simple window for testing the methods
controls = []
windowed = 'myWindow'
if cmds.window(windowed, q=True, exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI(windowed)
    cmds.windowPref(windowed, remove=True)

cmds.window(windowed, title='Updater UI', w=297, h=113)
cmds.showWindow(windowed)
cmds.frameLayout("main_layout", lv=False, mh=7)

# create the updater button
edge = 7
layout2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=2, adj=1, columnOffset=[(1, "left", edge), (2, "right", edge)],
                               columnSpacing=(2, 3),
                               parent=windowed)
add_btn = cmds.button(l="Add more buttons", c=addButtons, p=layout2)
remove_btn = cmds.button(l="Remove buttons", c=removeButtons, p=layout2)
# change parent to the top level layout of the window
cmds.setParent('|')

layout1 = cmds.columnLayout(adj=1, columnOffset=("both", edge), rs=5, parent=windowed)
cmds.button(l="Add Layout", c=addLayout, p=layout1)
cmds.button(l="Set parent Layout", c=setParentLayout, p=layout1)
# change parent to the top level layout of the window
cmds.setParent('|')
```